# Acoustic Input Data: Decibel or Pascals

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, data-preprocessing

In acoustics decibel levels were defined to solve an issue with showing values that are interpretive, understandable, and easy to communicate in contrast to intensity or pressure in Pascals.

$dB = 10*\log({\frac{p^2}{p_{ref}^2}})$

This log scale helps human understanding of an acoustic signal because human hearing is capable of discerning the difference of about 1 dB ref 20 $uPa$. However, if I have input data for a 2D CNN would it make more sense to have my input data be in Decibels where it is a logarithmic or to have raw pressures?

Would one or the other benefit my models learning?